# Automatic two-column before and after using memoir's sidebar?

Tags: memoir, multicol, sidebar

Is there a way to automatically switch out of twocolumn mode for pages that use memoir's "sidebar" command, and the back again once the sidebar has finished?  I can use multicol instead of twocolumn mode, if need be.

Comment: I... guess it's possible to do multiple passes, but it would require 100 compilation passes to converge. (unless you can afford breaking a page for the switch between 1 column and 2 column)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to put this as a comment but for some reason nothing happens when I click on "Add a comment". This has now happened for at least 2 days.

I believe that the answer is **NO**, certainly for plain `memoir` and I'm pretty sure it is also **NO** for using `multicol` with `memoir`. Have you tried it? Why do you want to do it?

Comment: I had hoped to be able to selectively exit two-column mode, in favor of a single column plus a sidebar, and have things go back again when the potentially multi-page sidebar was finished.  I no longer recall what attempts I made, but as a layman it was enough to exasperate me.